# Why doesn't the Javascript Swal Fire method work?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function musterisecme() {
        var musterilistesi = document.getElementById("musterilistesi");
        var secilendeger = musterilistesi.options[musterilistesi.selectedIndex].value;
        if (secilendeger == "musteri_ekle") {
            Swal.fire({
                title :"Dikkat!",
                text :"Müşteri ekleme sayfasına yönlendirilmek istediğinize eminmisiniz?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton:true
            })
        } 
    }
    </script>
```

My codes are that way but what could be the reason I am getting this error?

> Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined
>       at musterisecme (domainekle.php:314)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (domainekle.php:226)

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. What is it that you expect `Swal` to be?

Answer (score 1):

Could you check your CDN is correct for SweetAlert2 ?

If not, then use any of below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.29.2/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

Comment: was this the answer for you ? @FurkanKUBAT

Answer (score 0):

this error is produced because you are using the function Swal.fire before the CDN, so you have to put first the CDN and then you can use it.